# google.maps.FusionTablesLayer: styles not applied

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I got a code snippet below to display the boundary of an area from google map FusionTablesLayer. The polygon got displayed but the expected style never applied. What's wrong with my code? Please help me. Thank you alot.

```
var FT_TableID=420419;
var ftoptions = {
        suppressInfoWindows:true,
        styles: [
            {polygonOptions: {fillColor:'#0040FF',fillOpacity:0.1,strokeColor:'#FF0000',strokeWeight:2,strokeOpacity:0.6}}
        ]        
    };  


var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(FT_TableID,ftoptions);
layer.setQuery('SELECT \'kml_4326\' FROM 420419 WHERE \'name_0\' = \'Vietnam\';');

layer.setMap(theMap);
```

---

Thank you for the suggestion. Let me clarify my case further, why I had to write the code that way: I stored ftquery for each area in the database (in the raw format: SELECT ... FROM ...) and loaded it out to draw the area boundary.

```
var ftoptions = {...};
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(tableid);

//to load custom styles, but not work, same for setOptions or set('styles',styles);
layer.setValues(ftoptions);

var ftquery = '';//this is loaded from database
layer.setQuery(ftquery);
layer.setMap(theMap);
```

I tried your suggestion but the polygon did not show. I must be wrong somewhere. Thank you all for any further help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the "old" style syntax.  If you want to style the FusionTablesLayer, you need to use the [documented syntax](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesLayer)

```
var ftoptions = {
        query: {
          from: tableid,
          select: 'kml_4326',
          where: "name_0 = 'Vietnam'"
        },
        suppressInfoWindows:true,
        styles: [
            {polygonOptions: {fillColor:'#0040FF',fillOpacity:0.1,strokeColor:'#FF0000',strokeWeight:2,strokeOpacity:0.6    }}
        ]
    };

var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(ftoptions);
layer.setMap(theMap);
```